# Customized Serialize form on AJAX POST?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, django, post

I want to serialze form data on an AJAX POST request and

`$("#formid").serialze()` isn't suitable for me.

Is there a way I can get the results in a better format . Currently $("#formid").serialze() gives me the result as

```
`poststring="csrfmiddlewaretoken=bb9SOkN756QSgTbdJYDTvIz7KYtAdZ4A&colname=SPORT&datatype=VARCHAR2&field_size=20&null_constraint=1&default_val=&colname=HELLO&datatype=VARCHAR2&field_size=20&default_val=&colname=JUDY&datatype=VARCHAR2&field_size=20&default_val=&tablename=&fsize=&preview_flag=`
```

I want the POST request object to be

{"colname":[HELLO,JUDY,SPORT]...............}

with multiple row form inputs as arrays (if you know what I mean).

I thought of parsing the output from serialize() but then it could be buggy and can break with tricky column data.

I need the POST response to be in the format I mentioned

Comment: Nothing built in... you'd have to to write your own custom serializer.  You'll get a much better response, though, if you show a *minimal example* of the markup you are using and what you've tried on your own.  If you know the names you are after (such as `colname`), then `<form>.getElementsByName('colname')` will give you an array-like node-list you can start from.  Make an object with the data you wantm, then `JSON.stringify` that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to build a object has some key, and each key has an array to be value?
serialze() can`t solve your problem, you may need to write a new function.

---

you can set class to each inptu of your form,like class="colname" class="dataType", and you need to use $('.someClass').each() or other method to check your input and use array.push() to build an array.finally use some array to build a new object like you want.